# I was trying to upload video on firebase but it gives me an error

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

```
The method 'existsSync' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: existsSync()
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      StorageReference.putFile (package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart:62:17)
#2      _UploadState.uploadImage (package:focal/pages/upload.dart:402:10)
#3      _UploadState.handleVideoSubmit (package:focal/pages/upload.dart:507:30)
<asynchronous suspension>

#4      _UploadState.buildUploadForm.<anonymous closure>       (package:focal/pages/upload.dart:613:27)
#5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
#6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
#7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:504:11)
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._chec<…>
```

> What does this error means 
>   I was just uploading a video file and it gives me this error.
>
> This is my code below for uploading video

```
final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

 Future<String> uploadVideo(videoFile, String postId) async {
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef
    .child(
      'post_/$postId/${widget.currentuser.username}',
    )
    .putFile(videoFile);
String thumbnail = 'post_/$postId/${widget.currentuser.username}';
setState(() {
  thumbnailLocation = thumbnail;
});
StorageTaskSnapshot storageSnap = await uploadTask.onComplete;
String downloadUrl = await storageSnap.ref.getDownloadURL();
return downloadUrl;
```

}

Comment: Please share the exact widget code and methods you. Also edit your question to be better readable.

Comment: See above, and you are most likely doing existsSync(value) where value is null. Console.log the values you are passing into the function

Comment: The error means that the there is no file, you need to share your code to get any help

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have edited my code just have a look on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have initialized `storageRef`